# AJAX load more posts not using correct category and repeating the same few posts

Tags: posts, functions, categories, ajax, query

I have a page on a current project where I've successfully set up AJAX post filtering, so the user can click on a checkbox and filter the posts by the category the corresponds to it. I've also *mostly* successfully set up AJAX post loading where the user scrolls to the bottom and more posts are loaded in. I'll describe my problem and then post my code.

**My Problem**

When the new posts load in on scroll by AJAX, they aren't in the right category (or categories, depending on which checkboxes are clicked). Also, I have it set to load in 9 new posts at a time, and they're just repeating the same 9 posts every time.

**My Code**

In my functions.php file, I have the following code:

```
    // Setup AJAX for filter posts by category and for load more button
    function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
        // Enqueue script
        wp_register_script('afp_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
        wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

        global $wp_query;
        wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
                    'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                    'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
                    'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                    'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                )
        );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

    // Filter posts by category
    function prefix_load_cat_posts () {

            $cat_id = $_POST['category__in'];

                $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'category__in' => $cat_id,
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );

            $filter_posts = new WP_Query($args);
            ob_start ();

            if ( $filter_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $filter_posts->have_posts() ) : $filter_posts->the_post(); ?>

                <article class="article-card">
                    <header class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-img" style="background: url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'small' ); ?>') no-repeat center center; width: 100%; background-size: cover;"></div>
                        <?php the_title( "<h4 class='article-title'>", "</h4>" ) ?>
                        <p class="article-author">By
                            <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true), 15, '...'); ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="card-footer">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-article" role="button">Read Now</a>
                    </footer>
                </article>

                <?php $post_count = $filter_posts->current_post + 1; ?>
                <?php if ($post_count % 3 == 0): ?>

                <div class="ad-wrapper">
                    <?php the_ad(202070); ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                    endif;
                    endwhile; endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();

        $response = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        echo $response;

        die(1);
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );

    // AJAX Load More
    function afp_load_more() {
        $args = isset( $_POST['query'] ) ? array_map( 'esc_attr', $_POST['query'] ) : array();
        $args['post_type'] = isset( $args['post_type'] ) ? esc_attr( $args['post_type'] ) : 'post';
        $args['paged'] = esc_attr( $_POST['page'] );
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $args['category__in'] = $cat_id;
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['orderby'] = 'date';
        $args['offset'] = 9;
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 9;
        var_dump($args);
        ob_start();
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $loop->have_posts() ): while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
        ?>

        <article class="article-card">
            <header class="card-header">
                <div class="card-img" style="background: url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'small' ); ?>') no-repeat center center; width: 100%; background-size: cover;"></div>
                <?php the_title( "<h4 class='article-title'>", "</h4>" ) ?>
                <p class="article-author">By
                    <?php the_author(); ?>
                </p>
            </header>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true), 15, '...'); ?>
                </p>
                <p><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></p>
            </div>
            <footer class="card-footer">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-article" role="button">Read Now</a>
            </footer>
        </article>

        <?php $post_count = $loop->current_post + 1; ?>
        <?php if ($post_count % 3 == 0): ?>

        <div class="ad-wrapper">
            <?php the_ad(202070); ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        endif;
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
        $res = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        echo $res;
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_afp_load_more', 'afp_load_more' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_afp_load_more', 'afp_load_more' );
```

In my JavaScript file, I have this code:

```
// AJAX Post Filter scripts
var $checkbox = $("#filter input:checkbox");

let categoryIDs = [];

$checkbox.change((e) => {
  let value = Number(e.currentTarget.value);

  if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    categoryIDs.indexOf(value) === -1 ? (
      categoryIDs.push(value)
    ) : (
      categoryIDs = categoryIDs.filter((item) => item !== value)
    )
  } else {
    categoryIDs = [3, 4, 28, 35, 353];
    // TODO: move this to the functions.php file if possible? if/else to reset var to initial array if AJAX returns empty?
  }

  categoryIDs.forEach((item) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: "load-filter",
        category__in: categoryIDs
      },
      success: function (response) {
        $(".filter-section").empty().html(response);
        return false;
      }
    })
  });
});

// AJAX Load More Posts scripts
// TODO: Fix this.
var canBeLoaded = true;
var bottomOffset = 1200;
var page = 2;
var loading = false;
var scrollHandling = {
  allow: true,
  reallow: function () {
    scrollHandling.allow = true;
  },
  delay: 400
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (!loading && scrollHandling.allow) {
    scrollHandling.allow = false;
    setTimeout(scrollHandling.reallow, scrollHandling.delay);
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && canBeLoaded == true) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
        data: {
          action: "afp_load_more",
          page: page,
          query: afp_vars.query
        },
        success: function (res) {
          $(".filter-section").append(res);
          page += 1;
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

And lastly, I have this code in my template file:

```
      <!-- Filter Area -->
      <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <h4 class="ctr">Choose a Filter Below</h4>
          <div class="article-filters">
          <form id="filter">
            <?php
              $args = array(
                'include' => array(3, 4, 28, 35, 353),
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
              );

              $categories = get_categories($args);
                foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
                  $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $cat->name );

                  echo '<span>
                          <input class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" id="check'. $cat_id .'" name="category-checks" value="' . $cat_id . '">
                          <label class="checkbox-custom-label" for="check'. $cat_id .'">' . $cat->name . '</label>
                        </span>';
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div class="filter-section">
            <?php
              $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'category__in' => array(3, 4, 28, 35, 353),
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
              );

              $filter_posts = new WP_Query($args);
              if ( $filter_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $filter_posts->have_posts() ) : $filter_posts->the_post();
            ?>

            <article class="article-card">
              <header class="card-header">
                <div class="card-img" style="background: url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url( 'small' ); ?>') no-repeat center center; width: 100%; background-size: cover;"></div>
                <?php the_title( "<h4 class='article-title'>", "</h4>" ) ?>
                <p class="article-author">By <?php the_author(); ?></p>
              </header>
              <div class="card-content">
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true), 15, '...'); ?></p>
              </div>
              <footer class="card-footer">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-article" role="button">Read Now</a>
              </footer>
            </article>

            <?php $post_count = $filter_posts->current_post + 1; ?>
            <?php if ($post_count % 3 == 0): ?>

            <div class="ad-wrapper">
               <?php the_ad(202070); ?>
            </div>

            <?php
              endif;
              endwhile; endif;

              wp_reset_query();

            ?>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I used two or three different guides to patch this all together, so I'm sure I've made an error somewhere. Unfortunately, I can't figure out where. I don't expect anyone to do my work for me, but if you could help me find the problem, I'd be super grateful!

Comment: have you checked your categoryIDs var in ajax whether it is giving you correct IDs or not?

Comment: Your `afp_load_more()` function is setting `$args['category__in']` to `$cat_id`, but I don't see `$cat_id` being set anywhere in that function.

Comment: It does return correctly in my first function for the post filtering. I don't know how to get that value to the other function though.

Comment: Sorry that was from some code that didn't work which I deleted. I forgot to remove that line, too.

Comment: @KreigD set the categoryIDs variable same as you did for other function, the currently selected ones

Comment: @PiyushRawat Would that basically look like the `categoryIDs.forEach((item) => { $.ajax...` that I have for the other AJAX call? Just wrap that same forEach around the second AJAX call and include the category__in parameter in the data array?

Comment: no..set categoryIDs using your `if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {` block

Comment: try like this https://pastebin.com/9P2LBWiu

Comment: @PiyushRawat Thank you. I didn't end up using your solution, but it got my brain going in the right direction. Posted an answer with how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues this way:

In my functions.php file, I added the following code:

```
if (empty($cat_id)) {
    $cat_id = array(3, 4, 28, 35, 353);
}
```

In my second AJAX function like so:

```
function afp_load_more() {
  $cat_id = $_POST['category__in'];
  if (empty($cat_id)) {
    $cat_id = array(3, 4, 28, 35, 353);
  }
...etc
```

So that when the `categoryIDs` from my JavaScript returned an empty array (before a user clicks any checkboxes), it would default to the five categories chosen for the checkbox filters.

In my JavaScript, I didn't have to change much as I discoved the `categoryIDs` variable was usable by my second AJAX call as-is. The only change I made for that issues was to add `category__in: categoryIDs` to my second AJAX call under the data array.

For the issue of the repeating posts, I realized I just needed to set up a primative counter to add the value of the `posts_per_page` to the `offset` parameter in my query.

Here's my finished, working JavaScript for the load-on-scroll AJAX call (changes are noted in comments):

```
// AJAX Load More Posts scripts
var canBeLoaded = true;
var bottomOffset = 1500;
var page = 2;
var postOffset = 9; // Added a variable for the offset
var loading = false;
var scrollHandling = {
  allow: true,
  reallow: function () {
    scrollHandling.allow = true;
  },
  delay: 400
};

$(window).scroll(function () {

  if (!loading && scrollHandling.allow) {
    scrollHandling.allow = false;
    setTimeout(scrollHandling.reallow, scrollHandling.delay);
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && canBeLoaded == true) {
      loading = true; // This is important but I forgot it last time around
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
        data: {
          action: "afp_load_more",
          page: page,
          query: afp_vars.query,
          category__in: categoryIDs, // Added the variable from the first AJAX call here as-is because it's working now
          offset: postOffset // Added the offset parameter with the variable to give it the value
        },
        success: function (res) {
          $(".filter-section").append(res);
          page += 1;
          postOffset += 9; // Added a counter to add 9 to the offset on success because I load in 9 posts every time the AJAX call runs
          loading = false; // This is important, but I forgot it last time around
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Oh, and don't forget (like I did) to go back and use your data for the offset parameter from the AJAX call into the functions.php file (in the second AJAX function, with the rest of the `$args`). Like so:

```
$args['offset'] = esc_attr( $_POST['offset'] );
```

Hope this helps somebody else. And if anyone has a critique of my code that could make it better, ***please*** add your input!

Comment: Nice to see you sorted it out!!